# Command on python regarding age on a loop until a correct answer appears

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a command on python in which I ask the user to enter correct age of my brother. If the age 23 is entered, the program terminates saying "Good job". Otherwise, the user is again asked the age of my brother. I cannot understand how to make such a program. Below is my best guess:

```
age = input("what is the age of your brother? ")
while age = 23:
    print ("correct answer entered")
    else:
        print ("incorrect answer entered")
```

I am getting a syntax error

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparisons.

Comment: You need to ask for the new age in the loop. And it should be `while age != 23:`

Answer (score 3):

You need to ask for the age inside the loop, and end the loop when it's correct. And since `input()` returns a string, you need to compare it with a string, not an integer. To compare things you need to use `==`, not `=`.

```
while True:
    age = input("what is the age of your brother? ")
    if age == '23':
        print("correct answer entered")
        break
    else:
        print("incorrect answer entered")
```